# Error building xcode project with Google Places Api

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-places-api

I'm new to coding in xcode and I'm trying to import Google Places Api using CocaoPods but I keep running in to this error and have no clue what it means.

I've tried searching for answers but have not found anything close to a solution.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Saly.png)

Please... Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: if anymore information is needed, please comment and I'll include it in.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the build folder? (Command + Opition + Shift + K)